# Racket - How to assign a length to a list

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I was wondering, in racket, how would you assign a certain length to a list.

**This is the code I want to run:**

```
(check-expect (length a-list-of-length-104) 104)
```

How would you go about this without actually inputting 104 elements into the list?

**This is my end goal:**

```
(define (random-element a-list)
(list-ref a-list (random (length a-list))))

(random-element a-list-of-length-104)
(random-element a-list-of-length-104)
(random-element a-list-of-length-104)
```

It should produce a different output everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of a list is the number of elements it contains. So you can't "assign a length to a list".

However you can create a list with a certain number of elements, more conveniently. Assuming `#lang racket`, you can use [`build-list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._build-list%29%29).

To build a list consisting of the integers from 0 through 103:

```
(build-list 104 values)
```

To build a list consisting of 104 of random `real` numbers:

```
(build-list 104 (lambda _ (random)))
```

Comment: Ahh okay, I never knew about that function, however "values" doesn't work, it **keeps giving an error saying that the variable "values" is not defined.**

Comment: @Theo Sounds like you're working in one of the teaching languages, *not* Racket. The teaching languages are more restrictive than the full Racket language. Greg's solution will work fine in regular Racket, though.

Comment: @AlexisKing ahh okay makes sense, and yes I am working in the teaching language of racket

Comment: If `build-list` is in the teaching languages, change the first example to `(build-list 104 (lambda (n) n))`. That's all `values` really does here -- act as the identity function. [If `lambda` isn't in the student languages, I give up. :P]